# Hadoop giving SCDynamicStore on my JAR but not on hadoop-examples.jar

Tags: hadoop

I'm very confused about building and executing my first job in Hadoop and would love help from anyone who can clarify the error I am seeing and provide guidance :)

I have a JAR file that I've compiled. When I try to execute a M/R job using it in OSX, I get the SCDynamicStore error that is often associated with the HADOOP_OPTS environment variable. However, this does not happen when I run examples from the example JAR file. I have set the variable in hadoop-env.sh and it appears to be recognized in the cluster.

Running a test from hadoop-examples.jar works:

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.2/libexec/hadoop-examples-1.1.2.jar wordcount /stock/data /stock/count.out
13/06/22 13:21:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
13/06/22 13:21:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/06/22 13:21:51 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/06/22 13:21:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306221315_0003
13/06/22 13:21:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/22 13:21:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 66% reduce 0%
13/06/22 13:21:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/06/22 13:22:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
13/06/22 13:22:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/06/22 13:22:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201306221315_0003
...
```

Running a job using my own class does not work:

```
$ hadoop jar test.jar mapreduce.X /data /output
13/06/22 13:38:36 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/06/22 13:38:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/06/22 13:38:36 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/06/22 13:38:36 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
13/06/22 13:38:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306221328_0002
13/06/22 13:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/22 13:38:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201306221328_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory
    at mapreduce.VerifyMarket$Map.<clinit>(VerifyMarket.java:26)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:802)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapperClass(JobConf.java:947)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 22 more

attempt_201306221328_0002_m_000000_0: 2013-06-22 13:38:39.314 java[60367:1203] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
13/06/22 13:38:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201306221328_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
... (This repeats a few times, but hopefully this is enough to see what I mean.)
```

Initially, I thought this was related to the aforementioned environment variable, but now I'm not so sure. Maybe I'm packaging my JAR incorrectly?

Comment: Have you included gson?

Comment: Looks like that may have been it, I don't think that was in my classpath nor was it packaged into the JAR. Not confirmed yet, but that's at least a direction to check.

Comment: Well, even with the gson JAR explicitly listed in the classpath, it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Although it's not the ideal solution, but just to make sure, put the jar into your hadoop/lib folder and re-run the job.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Reading through http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/ now, this appears to go into detail on the issue.

Comment: Good find. I was about to point you to the Cloudera's post but this one looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer was to convert the project to Maven and include a `gson` dependency in the POM. Now `mvn package` picks up all the necessary dependencies and creates a single JAR file that contains everything necessary to complete the job in the cluster.